# Read xml files from Google cloud storage into pandas dataframe via jupyterkernel instance?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to read hundreds of xml files into a pandas dataframe on my google cloud instance.

I want to to it like this:

```
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucketname')

df = pd.DataFrame()

list_dfs = ()
#parsing the data into pandas df
for blob in bucket.list_blobs():
    data = pd.read_xml(blob.open(mode='rt', encoding='iso-8859-1'), compression='gzip')
    list.append(data)

df = pd.concat(list_dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

unfortunately I keep getting errors related to syntax errors in the xml files or UnicodeDecodeErrors. When I read the files that showed syntax errors on my local machine they don't throw any errors.

Can it be that I have to open the blob in a different way and only then read them into a df? I tried with `with open`but that also did not work. Does anyone know why I can't just directly read all the xml files via `pandas.read_xml()` from the bucket into a dataframe?

Comment: have you tried without the `encoding` parameter and/or with `mode='r'`?

Comment: @99_m4n yes I tried that, then I get the ```UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte```error again

Comment: with the encoding I get: ```lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1``` error. But I check it on local also with ```read_xml()``` and there is no syntax error in the file